# split string using regex every 6 digits

Tags: python-3.x, regex

i basically need to split a string before the next 6 digits and colon:

```
import re
my_str = '610640: 168 hours 610835: till next day 14:00 617041:  168 hours 611486:720 hours'
match = re.split(r'(\d{6}\:)', my_str)
print(match)
for item in match:
    print(item)
```

to read `610640: 168 hours` and `610835: till next day 14:00` and `617041:  168 hours` and so on. Other regex I've tried:

`(\d{6}\:)+.*?(\d{6}\:)`

i've been using https://pythex.org/ to get an idea of how\what to write the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the match you are almost there, but you should turn the last part in a lookahead instead of a match and to get the last item using an alternation to assert the end of the string.

In this part `(\d{6}\:)+` you can omit the group and the repetition as it occurs only 1 time and the colon does not have to be escaped.

```
 \b\d{6}:.*?(?=\s*(?:\d{6}:|$))
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PdmtOK/1)

If you want to use re.split, you might also use:

```
(?<!^)\b(?=\d{6}:)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i82keV/1)

```
import re
my_str = '610640: 168 hours 610835: till next day 14:00 617041:  168 hours 611486:720 hours'
match = re.split(r'(?<!^)\b(?=\d{6}:)', my_str)
print(match)
for item in match:
    print(item.strip())
```

Output

```
['610640: 168 hours ', '610835: till next day 14:00 ', '617041:  168 hours ', '611486:720 hours']
610640: 168 hours
610835: till next day 14:00
617041:  168 hours
611486:720 hours
```

If there are always 1 or more leading whitespace chars, you could match them to split on and omit the word boundary:

```
match = re.split(r'\s+(?=\d{6}:)', my_str)
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qqNn8E).

Comment: Thank you :) i'm going to check out each option you've attached to the regex, will accept ansswer in 10m. Its working 100% :)

Comment: Indeed `\s+(?=\d{6}:)` should be good enough